# Focus mode for a field in swift: How to dim/blur all the screen except the active field

Tags: swift, uikit

I'd like to create a "focus mode" when all the screen is masked/blurred while the user is typing in a field or a text view. I can create a `UIVisualEffectView` with `UIScreen.main.bounds` size as a background for the field and show it on `didBeginEditing`, but I have super views, including a SplitViewController, with the clipping to bounds, so I can't go outside parent's bounds even if I bring the field to the front with `bringSubview(toFront:)`. I can create a new empty controller, send the field to this controller, keeping the field position in the new coordinates, and present this controller to the full screen, but I don't believe it's the easiest solution ;-)

Comment: You can add the `UIVisualEffectView` to the `UIWindow`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. How can I separate my field from the other views? They are all part of the main window after all. No?

Comment: I just add a view on top of the hierarchy (any size I want), color the background with gray or black, then set its transparency so that you can barely see the items underneath, then I bring the text view to the front so that it's on top of the alpha view. Then simply remove it from the hierarchy when done.

Comment: Thanks! You create a view with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last?.addSubview(viewToAdd)` right? How do you bring the textView to the front?